# How operator precedence works between % and //?

Tags: python, python-3.x, operators, modulus, floor-division

```
5 % 4 // 6 % 3
```

o/p is 0, but according to operator precedence it should raise a ZeroDivisionError because it should be interpreted as

```
5 % 0 % 3
```

resulting in an error

Can somebody please elaborate how operator precedence works here?

Comment: % and // have same precedence as you can see here: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html. Why do you think // should be executed first?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
5 % 4 // 6 % 3
```

just evaluates left to right
so

```
5%4 = 1
1//6 = 0
0%3 = 0
```

they are all at the same precedence level
https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence

Answer (score 0):

It is left to right. If you change your code for :

```
(5 % 4) // (6 % 3)
```

it raises a `ZeroDivisionError` , since parenthesis have precedence. If you don't put parenthesis it's only from left to right.